# If Statements are only looped once

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame, keypress

hi there my if statements in pygame are only being executed once, then after executing them they no longer work...  heres some of my menu code (simple keypresses):

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            import game
        if event.key == pygame.K_i:
            import Instructions
        if event.key == pygame.K_c:
            import controls
```

then heres some of my main game code (again keypresses):

```
if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                import menu
```

ok now say if i was in the menu and pressed space to start the (it works perfectly) it goes to the game module then starts the game, then if i press escape if i have opened the game module manually (not by pressing space), it also works perfectly however if i run the game from pressing the space key and then pressing escape to return to the menu nothing happens, so it only works if i have opened it directly by opening the game module itself. Also the working keypresses are only working once and one time only, so if i press space from the menu and then escape and then space again it just stays at the menu, so how will i slao make these "if" loops infinite

Comment: Do you think `if` is a looping construct? You must be confusing it with `while`. But I don't understand why you'd want to loop on `import` statements.

Comment: Why the hell somebody starred this one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the purpose of the `import` statement. An `import` is designed to "load" a python script. You shouldn't use it as a way to run all the code in another python file.

For example, let's say your game.py file looks like this:

```
a = 'Test'
print 'Running...'
```

Then, your main.py file looked like this:

```
import game
import game
import game
```

When you run main.py, the first `import` occurs. This causes the `game` module to be loaded . This means that the `game.py` script is run, and all the variables/functions/etc defined there a defined in the `game` module.

Think about how you use pygame. You used an `import pygame` line. The goal here was not to "run" a pygame script, but instead to give yourself access to what is in the `pygame` module.

What you want to do is create a function in your game.py file:

```
def run():
    print 'Running...'
```

To get the print to happen multiple times, you would call the `run()` function from main.py multiple times...

```
import game

game.run()
game.run()
game.run()
```

This will cause the code that you defined in the `run()` function of the `game.py` file (aka the `game` module) to run multiple times.

Comment: ive got no idea how to define run, im like 3 weeks new to programming and this game is for my a-level computing coursework.
But i have tried to make a while loop with my import contrls in them:
close = False
while close == False:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            import game
        if event.key == pygame.K_i:
            import Instructions
        if event.key == pygame.K_c:
            import controls
            close = True

Comment: @user2815879: I would recommend, then, that for now you put all of your code into one file until you have understood how modules and functions work.